# Unix / Linux command to add 30 mins to the numeric string

Tags: linux, unix-timestamp

I have used the below commands to find the 30 mins older time but not able to frame commands to add 30 mins.

Sample structure of input.

```
dateinput=20181214202959
inputTime=$(echo $dateinput | sed 's,\(.\{4\}\)\(.\{2\}\)\(.\{2\}\)\(.\{2\}\)\(.\{2\}\),\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:,')
param2=`date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S' --date="$inputTime 30 minutes ago"`
echo $param2
20181214195959
```

Please let me know the steps to add 30 mins similar to the above one. For the sample dateinput given above the desired output is 20181214205959.

Edit:

With the direct date command i am able to add and reduce based on the requirement given below :

```
$date
Tue Dec 18 20:49:06 PST 2018
$date --date "-30 minutes"
Tue Dec 18 20:18:55 PST 2018
$date --date "+30 minutes"
Tue Dec 18 21:19:01 PST 2018
```

My requirement is to get the date from the input which will be given like 20181214202959 which is in YYYYMMDDhhmmss format. This is where I am facing issues. Able to reduce the time using "30 minutes ago" command but not able to get the future value for the given time.

Comment: Your `param2` backquote isn't closed.

Comment: That was a typo and thanks for notifying. Corrected it now. Not facing any issues when subtracting time but adding.

Answer (score 1):

Use `+30 minutes`, e.g.:

```
$ date
Tue Dec 18 17:48:22 GMT 2018
$ date --date "-30 minutes"
Tue Dec 18 17:18:26 GMT 2018
$ date --date "+30 minutes"
Tue Dec 18 18:18:32 GMT 2018
```

Comment: Didn’t work. Tried it earlier and got error message saying not a desired date format.

Comment: @SekarRamu Try it without `$inputTime` and the format first.

Comment: With standard date command even I was able to get it but here I have to get the date from the input which I am getting and to that date I have add 30 mins. While passing +30 minutes to that input date I am getting issues. Could you please let me know in how to add 30 mins to that kind of input which I have mentioned in the question?

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue. use "30 minutes ago" to get the past value and just "30 minutes" to get the future value.

```
$dateinput=20181214202959
$inputTime=$(echo $dateinput | sed 's,\(.\{4\}\)\(.\{2\}\)\(.\{2\}\)\(.\{2\}\)\(.\{2\}\),\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:,')
$param2=`date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S' --date="$inputTime 30 minutes ago"`
$echo $param2
20181214195959
$param3=`date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S' --date="$inputTime 30 minutes"`
echo $param3
20181214205959
```